# Avoid following link when using org-return-follows-link and point is at end of line

Tags: org-mode, customize

The option `org-return-follows-link` is wonderfully convenient **except** when the point is at the end of the line where the intention is usually to insert a carriage return.

What's the best way to change this behavior to insert a carriage return in this edge case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made the following modification to `org-return`.  I'll change the correct answer if a better one is offered.

```
  ((and org-return-follows-link
+   (not (eolp))
    (or (org-at-timestamp-p t)
        (org-at-date-range-p t)
       (org-in-regexp org-any-link-re)))
```

Comment: You might want to use `eolp` instead of comparing point manually: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Near-Point.html . Also, this would be a great contribution to org-mode.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `oelp`.  It's definitely the behavior *I* want, but technically the point is within the link pattern.  Some people might consider it sloppy behavior :-\

Comment: At least bring it up. It might be a nice preference to set, if it's not the default.

Comment: It doesn't just happen within/after `[[org][links]]` - if you paste a url into a blank line and hit return, the link is followed. Thanks for this solution. Using Org-mode 8.3.3-2-g6bc48c-elpa.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer this, as it simply disables follow-link:

```
;point at eol should not follow link
(defun my/org-return ()
  "disable org-return-follows-link if at bol or eol"
  (interactive)
  (let* ((follow org-return-follows-link)
         (org-return-follows-link (and follow (not (or (bolp) (eolp))))))
    (org-return)))
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<return>") 'my/org-return)
```

Also, I just noticed that what I really want is this:

```
;C-m should always just edit text
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-m") 'newline-and-indent)
```

Answer (score 0):

my soluton for history purpose. Patch for original code not needed.

```
   (defun bss/my-org-return ()
     "Insert newline if we at beginng or end of line"
     (interactive)
     (if (or (eolp) (bolp))
      (newline-and-indent)
    (org-return)))
   (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<return>") 'bss/my-org-return)
```